# I'm gettng the error AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'

Tags: django-models

I am getting this error

Your leads are appreciated

```
File ~\Desktop\freecodecamp\mysite\polls\models.py:16, in Question.was_published_recently(self)
     15 def was_published_recently(self):
---> 16     return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try importing like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```

eg:

```
timedelta(days=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

because timedelta is part of `datetime` main module not `datetime.datetime`.
try:

```py
import datetime

datetime.datetime
datetime.timedelta
```

Comment: was helpful, thank you.

Comment: happy to help. If the answer was what you were looking for please accept it as answer to your question.